# Android Pinch Zoom on editText

Tags: android, android-edittext, pinchzoom

Is there any way to add pinch zoom in zoom out on edit Text?

Answer (score 1):

**This is working for me**

you have to create a custom edittext and  impelements `ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener`.

**xt might look like that**

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText implements ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener {

private float textSize=14f;
private float maxTextSize=40f;
private float minTextSize=5f;
private ScaleGestureDetector sgdetector;

public MyEditText(Context context,AttributeSet attr){
    super(context,attr);
    sgdetector=new ScaleGestureDetector(context,this);
    sgdetector.setQuickScaleEnabled(true);
}
@Override
public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector gesture) {
    float prs = gesture.getPreviousSpan();
    float spn = gesture.getCurrentSpan();
    float spt = gesture.getScaleFactor();
    if(prs>spn){
        textSize-=spt;
        textSize = Math.max(textSize,minTextSize);
    }else{
        textSize+=spt;
        textSize = Math.min(textSize,maxTextSize);
    }
    setTextSize(textSize);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector gesture) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector gesture) {

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    sgdetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return sgdetector.isInProgress() ? true : super.onTouchEvent(event);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a bit of strange user interaction, I believe it should be able to be done by just combining some simple view gesture recognition and changing the font size. You could begin by creating a custom `EditText` and overriding the `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` method. In `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)`, you can make use of `ScaleGestureDetector` (more info [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.html)) to detect "pinch-to-zoom" gestures. Also take a look at this Android [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale.html) for more info on implementing custom gesture detections in views.

After you detect the zooming gesture, you can simply use `setTextSize` in `EditText` to adjust the size of the font relative to the change in zoom. This of course isn't going to give you a *smooth* zooming gesture like zooming on a website. Another method you could try is taking the zoom gesture and physically adjusting the size (width and height) of the `EditText` but that's just a thought.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks brian for replying ....i already gone through it....and i tried for scaling and GestureDetector but some how its not working

Comment: brian i am implementing one edittext wich is movable and when user wants its use pinch zoom effect ....but after trying so many solution zoom is not working.....some how i manage to move  edit text with library..//

Answer (score 0):

This code does the job, you have to add `super.onTouchEvent(event);` so you don't lose EditText properties

```
final static float move = 200;
float ratio = 1.0f;
int bastDst;
float baseratio;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    super.onTouchEvent(event);
    if (event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        int mainaction = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
        if (mainaction == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) {
            bastDst = getDistance(event);
            baseratio = ratio;
        } else {
            // if ACTION_POINTER_UP then after finding the distance
            // we will increase the text size by 15
            float scale = (getDistance(event) - bastDst) / move;
            float factor = (float) Math.pow(2, scale);
            ratio = Math.min(1024.0f, Math.max(0.1f, baseratio * factor));
            text.setTextSize(ratio + 15);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// get distance between the touch event
private int getDistance(MotionEvent event) {
    int dx = (int) (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
    int dy = (int) (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
    return (int) Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}
```